# How can I reuse plastic shopping bag?

Tags: plastics, shopping

After shopping we have a lot of plastic shipping bag. If we burn these bag then its harmfull for envoirnment and we can not burried it. What is the best solution of resuse of a plastic shopping bag.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid the problem: I bring my own reusable bags when I go shopping, and I decline any bags offered by shop personnel.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using them to line smaller bins works, as well as holding wet clothes in a bag is a great use to prevent them from going into the environment!

Depending on which country you're in too, some stores might also be able to recycle them through a dedicated program - for example, in Australia, we have the [RedCycle Program](https://www.redcycle.net.au/).

Comment: Its the problem of Pakistan

Comment: Gotcha. I did a quick search on Google and found [this](http://www.iisrecycling.com/services.html) company that offers a recycling solution - although I'm not sure if it works for you. You can probably find some local alternatives by searching!

Comment: recycling is always a good way to use plastic bags.  Sometimes they may pay you for it.